# unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's execute method in the partial trust domain

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sandbox-solution, sharepoint-on-prem

The below Error was thrown while activating the feature in SharePoint Sandboxed solution in Sharepoint-2013.

> unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's
>   execute method in the partial trust domain

From ULS log:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeSolutionProxiedException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers. Server stack trace: at ******.ListDefinition.Features.******.SiteColumn_Feature.******EventReceiver.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties) at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeFeatureCallOutWrapper.ExecuteInternal(Object userCodeObject, SPUserCodeRemoteExecutionContext context) at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeRemoteExecutionWrapper.Execute(SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)

Please suggest the steps to fix this issue.

Comment: [This link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ca2e65ec-0b28-495b-b5e0-4c00bc5d7c4f/that-assembly-does-not-allow-partially-trusted-callers-in-dashboard-viewer-webform-application?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious) suggests the issue could be fixed by deploying the solution as a Farm solution. Is that an option in your case?

Comment: @moe Sorry that link was not relevant to my Query,I have Uploaded my Sandboxed WSP in Solution Galleries and on Activating the feature it shows the error

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that your assembly has a strong name.

Also, you can try to add [[assembly:AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.allowpartiallytrustedcallersattribute.aspx) attribute to the assembly.